# bayesian prob question?

Tags: probability

Question:

> Imagine you work at a computer repair shop. Over the years you have
> become experienced at diagnosing problems associated with different
> types of hardware. In particular, when a “TX1000” brand computer stops
> working, it is due to a cooling fan problem $30\%$ of the time. If the
> cooling fan is broken, there is a $45\%$ probability that the hard drive
> is also broken. If the cooling fan is okay, there is only a $5\%$ chance
> that the hard drive is broken.
>
> A customer brings you a computer that is not working. After a quick
> investigation, you determine that the hard drive is broken. What is
> the probability that the computer has a bad cooling fan?

I'm not sure if I am solving this question right. I am assuming its a bayesian probability question. Assuming that I have calculated these numbers:

$.45\cdot.3= 0.135\tag{1}$

## cooling fan and hard drive broken

$.55\cdot.3 =0.165\tag{2}$

## cooling fan broken, hard drive ok

$$.05\tag{3}$$

## cooling fan ok, hd broken

$$.95\tag{4}$$

## if cooling fan not ok, hard drive broken

So far I've calculated:

$$A \cap B= \frac{.135\cdot.05}{(.135\cdot.05)+(.165\cdot.95)}=0.0412844\cdot100\%=4.13\%$$ chance of a bad cooling fan.

Something seems conceptually wrong about this though. I feel like I'm messing up the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you went a little off track in your calculation. I'll start at the beginning and work through so you can see where the difference occurs:

**First**, some definitions of events: H = Hard drive broken, C=cooling fan broken

**Second**: What do we know:

$P(C)=.3, \\P(C^c)=1-P(C)=.7,\\P(H|C)=.45,\\P(H|C^c)=.05$

**Third**: What do we want to know? $P(C|H)$

You are correct that this is a Bayes theorem question. We can assemble the pieces below using the information we have:

$P(C|H)=\frac{P(H\cap C)}{P(H)}=\frac{P(C)P(H|C)}{P(C)P(H|C)+P(C^c)P(H|C^c)}=\frac{(.3)(.45)}{(.3)(.45)+(.7)(.05)}=\frac{.135}{.17}\approx 79\%$

You went off track in the denominator, where you are multpilying joint probabilities instead of an unconditional times a conditional to get the "partitions" of event H. Notice that in my denominator we end up with $P(H\cap C)+P(H\cap C^c)$ since these two events are mutually exclusive and exhaustive (the fan is either broken or it isn't), you can add them to get the total probability of H (i.e., [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability))

This makes intuitive sense as well, as it is far more likely that the hard drive would be broken if the fan were broken (Likelihood ratio/bayes factor of $\frac{.45}{.05} = 9$)

Comment: thank you! idk why i was messing up. i think i just got confused what value i was trying to find the intersect of.